# Emacs: how to stop jedi?

Tags: emacs, emacs-jedi

I regularly use [jedi.el](http://tkf.github.io/emacs-jedi/latest/), it works great. But I don't know how to stop it !

I manually call it with `jedi:setup` (which turns jedi-mode on) and try to stop it with `jedi-mode` but it has no effect. It is unconvenient and it gets in the way with yasnippet.

Do you have a solution ? Thanks.

config: emacs24 and latest jedi.el version from melpa. Result of `jedi:show-setup-info`:

```
;; Emacs Lisp version:
(:emacs-version "24.3.1" :jedi-version "0.2.0alpha2" :python-environment-version "0.0.2alpha0")
;; Python version:
((:version "2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:58:35) \n[GCC 4.6.3]" :name "sys" :file nil)
 (:version "0.7.0" :name "jedi" :file "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jedi/__init__.pyc")
 (:version "0.0.5" :name "epc" :file "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/epc/__init__.pyc")
 (:version "0.0.3" :name "sexpdata" :file "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sexpdata.pyc"))
;; Command line:
(:virtualenv "/usr/bin/virtualenv" :virtualenv-version "1.7.1.2\n")
;; Customization:
((jedi:complete-on-dot)
 (jedi:doc-display-buffer . display-buffer)
 (jedi:doc-hook view-mode)
 (jedi:doc-mode . rst-mode)
 (jedi:environment-root)
 (jedi:environment-virtualenv)
 (jedi:get-in-function-call-delay . 1000)
 (jedi:get-in-function-call-timeout . 3000)
 (jedi:goto-definition-config
  (nil nil nil)
  (t nil nil)
  (nil definition nil)
  (t definition nil)
  (nil nil t)
  (t nil t)
  (nil definition t)
  (t definition t))
 (jedi:goto-definition-marker-ring-length . 16)
 (jedi:imenu-create-index-function . jedi:create-nested-imenu-index)
 (jedi:import-python-el-settings . t)
 (jedi:install-imenu)
 (jedi:install-python-jedi-dev-command "pip" "install" "--upgrade" "git+https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi.git@dev#egg=jedi")
 (jedi:key-complete .
                    [C-tab])
 (jedi:key-goto-definition .
                           [67108910])
 (jedi:key-goto-definition-pop-marker .
                                      [67108908])
 (jedi:key-related-names . "r")
 (jedi:key-show-doc . "d")
 (jedi:server-args)
 (jedi:server-command "python" "/home/vdardelx/.emacs.d/elpa/jedi-20140321.1323/jediepcserver.py")
 (jedi:setup-keys)
 (jedi:tooltip-method pos-tip popup)
 (jedi:use-shortcuts)
 (python-environment-default-root-name . "default")
 (python-environment-directory . "~/.emacs.d/.python-environments")
 (python-environment-virtualenv "virtualenv" "--system-site-packages" "--quiet"))
```

Comment: `M-x imperial-order RET 66 RET` ?

Comment: I beg your pardon ? Google nor my emacs nor I know that command.

Comment: Apologies, Ehvince; it was [a dumb Star Wars joke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Jedi_Purge) that I couldn't resist, given the question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What aspect is conflicting with yasnippet? Is it the use of `autocomplete-mode`? (which seems to be the other broad consequence of running `jedi:setup`, and which isn't turned off again when `jedi-mode` is disabled.)

`M-x autocomplete-mode` will toggle that off again, or call `(autocomplete-mode -1)` in code.

You could write a function to disable both modes together, and call that to turn jedi off. A more robust approach would remember the state of autocomplete-mode at the time jedi was enabled in order to restore it afterwards, but it sounds like that's not critical in your case.